# IndexError: list index out of range error while multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I am getting a subscript out of range error that I cant seem to get pass for some reason, Any help would be greatly appreciated?

I have changed the variables to get this to work but its still not working out. The thread argument seems like it doesn't take in my two variables for some reason

Thanks

```
from threading import Thread
import urllib.request
import re

    def th(ur):
        base = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+ur
        regex = '<span id="yfs_184_'+ur.lower()+'">(.+?)</span>'
        pattern = re.compile(regex)
        htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(base).read().decode('utf-8')
        results = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
        print ("the price of "+str(ur)+" is "+str(results[0]))


    symbolslist = ["aapl","goog"]

    print (symbolslist)

    threadlist = []

    for u in symbolslist:
        t = Thread(target = th, args= (u,))
        t.start()
        threadlist.append(t)

    for b in threadlist:
        b.join()
```

Full traceback:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/Hellopython.py
['aapl', 'goog']
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 869, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/Hellopython.py", line 12, in th
    print ("the price of "+str(ur)+" is "+str(results[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 869, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/Hellopython.py", line 12, in th
    print ("the price of "+str(ur)+" is "+str(results[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: where are you getting the error exactly ? attach the full traceback

Comment: You don't check at the length of results when you extract element [0] -- that seems an possible offender.

Comment: I have attached the full traceback. I am playing around with the variables and have reduced them to two ("aapl",''goog") still am having problems trying to get it to work due to the IndexError: list index out of range error.

Comment: Hi Klamer Schutte, how do I check the length of the results when i extract element [0]? Thanks

Comment: `if len(results) > 0:`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with multithreading, it's just because `results` is an empty list. As the comment said, check it's lenght before printing.

```
def th(ur):
    base = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+ur
    regex = '<span id="yfs_184_'+ur.lower()+'">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(base).read().decode('utf-8')
    results = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    if len(results) > 0:
        print("the price of "+str(ur)+" is "+str(results[0]))
    else:
        print("results is empty")
```